# Doubt on compact supports for differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry

Poincare's lemma for differential forms with compact support states that given $\ U=(a_1,b_1)\times \dots \times (a_n,b_n)\subset \Bbb R^n $, one has that if $\omega\in\Omega^{n-1}_c$, then $\int_U d\omega=0$. (Here $\Omega^k_c$ is the set of $k-$differential forms with compact support over $U$). However I don't understand very well what does compact support mean, because if I consider the $1-$form $f(x)dx$ with $f(x)=(cos\ x +1)\mathcal X_{[-\pi,\pi]}$, I have $\int_U d\omega\neq 0$, although to me $[-\pi,\pi]$ seems compact. I'm sure the misunderstanding is in the definition of compact support, so thank you in advance.

Comment: $\omega$ might not $\mathscr{C}^1$, and anyway $d(f(x)dx)=0$ always holds if $f$ is $\mathscr{C}^1$.

Comment: What are the intervals $(a_1,b_1)$  and $(a_2,b_2)$ in your purported example?

Comment: Remember the definition of support.